# Unable to setup SharePoint Framework Dev Environment: TypeError: lookup.flatMap is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, nodejs, yeoman-generator

I am unable to setup SPFx Development Environment for my SharePoint Online. I installed 10.24 and 10.20 version of Nodejs then also installed gulp and yeoman. But when I execute **yo @microsoft/sharepoint** command, the nodejs command prompt throws error as shown in below picture. I tried multiple times to uninstall and reinstall 10.x versions of nodejs but the error is same. I am not able to find any information about this error on google.

> TypeError: lookup.flatMap is not a function

[image]

Comment: Hi Zakir, Can you please run the following command    "npm list -g --depth=0" and post screen shot here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the issue related to yeoman. You can fix this issue by downgrading it from 4.0.0 to 3.1.1

```
npm install yo@3.1.1 -g
```

**This combination does not work**

- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
- gulp@4.0.2
- npm@6.14.11
- **yo@4.0.0**

**This combination works**

- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
- gulp@4.0.2
- npm@6.14.11
- **yo@3.1.1**

[Similar question was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231581/spfx-development-environment-trouble-has-anyone-seen-lookups-flatmap-error/67253790#67253790).

Comment: Thanks a ton Denis. Your solution worked perfectly. The issue was related to yeoman version.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have installed only one version of nodejs at a time. For SPFx generator SharePoint online you will require v10.24.0 of nodejs.

Open command prompt and run following command in CMD to check global version of package

`npm list -g --depth=0`

Ideally it should display following following version

```
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0

+-- gulp@4.0.2

+-- npm@6.14.11

-- yo@3.1.1
```

If you have multiple version of nodejs without using nvm then it will not work.

For more details you can refer the this Microsoft docs.

[Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Comment: Yes @Rajat Sahani, one can only install one version of npm at a time. I had installed 10.20 and 10.24 nodejs version at one time. I have npm installed and its upto the lastest version.

Comment: have you unistall old one before intalling new one?

Comment: Yes I did that.